# Preferences & CheckBoxes

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm currently coding my LogIn class, which is where it gets the users' log info and submits it to the serve to be checked and if correct puts an intent to another class and if not it displays a toast, also, I'm going to put in a progress bar.

Anyway, I have a checkbox that says "Stay Signed In" I would like to know how I could set up a preferences that would bypass the login screen, but still check the login details.

Thanks

My Code so far:

```
package com.gta5news.bananaphone;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LogIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button send;
EditText user;
EditText pass;
CheckBox staySignedIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
}

private void SetUpVariables() {
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogIn);
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTuser);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTpassword);
    staySignedIn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Cbstay);

     if (staySignedIn.isChecked()){

    }

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bLogIn:
        String u = user.getText().toString();
        String p = pass.getText().toString();
        Bundle send = new Bundle();
        send.putString("key", u);
        send.putString("key", p);
        Intent a = new Intent(LogIn.this, FTPClient.class);
        startActivity(a);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Yay, you signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i that checkbox is checked you can use the previous inserted info to login automatically without pressing the button